# Smart cards data contents

Tags: applet, nfc, smartcard, javacard, apdu

I want to communicate with a smart card by MCU, my MCU supports ISO7816 protocol and as I know I must use APDU commands which are specified in ISO7816-4 protocol.

With a glimpse to APDU instructions there are some idioms I'm not familiar with. For example in reading/writing a "File", what does the word "File" refer to?

In the Mifare classic 1K memory divided based on the
 [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWTG1.png) & there is a simple sequence to read/write each section.

Is there any equivalent information about data structure of contact smart cards? How is data stored? How can we access/read/write these structures? Is there any specific document focused in this subject?

**EDIT:**
In the card's file management system,is file's size constant or it can be variable depend on files data?

Comment: Do you want to communicate with a specific smart card or with any of them?

Comment: This is every thing i know,I don't know there are specific protocols or not, Is this possible to communicate with a universal protocol to all of them? How many appraches there are ?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for examples in reading/writing File ,File word refer to what?
```

File - A logical view of memory. ISO/IEC 7816 -4 tells about file system, can read something [Here](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_5_basic_organizations.aspx)

Some specific cards like Mifare [**Memory card**][**no file concept, data stored block wise**] is ready by specific commands  like - load key, authenticate_with_card, Read_block. these commands are well defined by IFD.

Ex - if  you want to read Mifare card and you are using SCM reader, [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQhOqmy-rNAhVMRo8KHSAvCCsQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.identive-infrastructure.com%2Fpdf%2Fusa%2FSCL01x.MANUAL.VER2.0.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGmqCUwAZx3XUGiO7g2MfM_Juqp0w&sig2=gyh38iQy2Gfsud8b6Eb1Dg&bvm=bv.126130881,d.c2I)
document will help you to perform Read / Write operation.

```
 Is there any equivalent information about data structure of contact smart cards ? how data stored?
```

ISO 7816 tells about file structure of the card but all contact smart card does not follow it. sometimes programming is like -you just read the data from the card with sending APDU and you will get the data as a response.

and same way you can send data with Lc byte of apdu and it will store in the card.

To reading data from the card , it would be good to know about the card, get the specification from card vendor. That would help to explore the card.

Hope this information will help.

[update]

```
I searched local market & I found: 1-ACOS series from advanced cards systems 2- jcop from mifare 3- gemalto products. I think number 2 and 3 are kind of java cards,am i true?
```

JCOP [tool] is a java card tool that helps to code / debug/install applet of java card. I used Jcop plugin with eclipse IDE to develop java card applet. it is very good plugin,

Mifare is not java card , its a memory card and Gemalto have different products, how can you say that all are java card. Do some more resarch please.

Comment: :Really thank for your great information.I Edited my question & included some new extra information,hope keep me informed with new information,WBR.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have required points to do that.please accept my apologies.

Comment: see my edited answer. and for ACOS read the link you shared, you can get good information from there.

Comment: For  ACOS6S that mentioned above I cant access to the references manual.Is this need an a specific registration ?Is this possible communicate with this card without this manual?WBR.

Comment: if you have the chip, you can ask for specification from the chip vendor

Comment: JCOP is not a tool, is a Javacard Operating System (one of the most widely available, made by NXP). If you want to learn about smart cards it is probably a good idea to get hold of some samples.

Comment: @mictter JCOP itself stands for Java Card Open Platform (now Global Platform). It was created by IBM research labs, BlueZ team near Zurich. It's indeed a Java Card runtime (VM + API implementation + GP functionality). It was sold to NXP who was the major manufacturer releasing JCOP cards. The JCOP tools are a development and debugging environment which is nowadays a set of two Eclipse IDE "features" (plugins).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes +1, exactly. Thanks for completing the info!